# Reason to create new queue after every Dequeue()

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

This is code from an internal tool that I've inherited:

```
while (listThreadsRunning != null)
{
    listThreadsRunning.RemoveAll(mre => mre.Key.IsSet);

    if ((listThreadsRunning.Count < maxThreads || maxThreads == 0) && queueThreads.Any())
    {
        queueThreads = new Queue<KeyValuePair<ManualResetEventSlim, ThreadInput>>(queueThreads);

        var eventThreadPair = queueThreads.Dequeue();

        if (!eventThreadPair.Key.IsSet)
        {
            listThreadsRunning.Add(eventThreadPair);

            eventThreadPair.Value.Worker.Start();
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(SleepOperationTime.Instance.time);
}
```

`queueThreads` is a private variable instantiated with this type in the constructor and the queue is constantly populated by other threads. Why is the queue being recreated every time? I don't think there's a good reason for this but, if there is, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Probably a question for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yeah that really serves no purpose.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: A guess: is it possible that other threads have a reference to queueThreads? Could those threads possibly be trying to enqueue items while the code you've quoted is calling .Dequeue()? If so, perhaps the original author chose to copy the queue instead of implementing some more typical type of synchronization.

Comment: @PaulF may be correct about the intent, but this code looks unsafe regardless.  Constructing a new queue from the existing one will require enumerating its contents, and if other threads try to enqueue items while enumeration is taking place then it the enumerator will throw an exception.  This code should either use a thread-safe container (e.g. ConcurrentQueue) or make use of lock statements.